# Hyperlink field in salesforce1 mobile app

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-field, formula-field, hyperlink

I have a custom formula field "Create Activity" in one of the object and it has a hyperlink value such that clicking it pass some parameters such Account name, Contact name etc. from current webpage (where it's clicked) to the webpage for creating activity.

This works in desktop but does not work in salesforce1 mobile app as it's URL based. **How to make URL with parameters to work in salesforce1?** Below is the formula for the field.

```
HYPERLINK("/00U/e?CF00N1600000EtQzK_lkid=" & SecAccount__r.Id&"&who_id="&Contact__r.Id& "&what_id=" & Project__r.Id & "&CF00N1600000EtQzK=" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SecAccount__r.Name,"#","%23"),"&","%26"),"$","%24"),"+","%2B")," ","%20")&"&retURL=%2F"&Project__r.Id,"Create Acitivity", "_blank")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use URL hacks in Salesforce 1, you should consider using action or a visualforce page depending on our requirement. Check out this blog post: 
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/visualforce-in-salesforce1.html